# how to add values from select statement as a new column

Tags: sql, join, select, case

i have my table as

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    ReportsTo       Position    Age
8   Ashley      Johnson     null            Intern      25  
5   Noah        Fritz       Jenny Richards  Assistant   30  
6   David       S           Jenny Richards  Director    32  
3   Jenny       Richards    null            CEO         45
```

i want to add a column as "Boss title" to above table with values from below select statement. but it is not working.

```
SELECT *,
    case when ReportsTo='Jenny Richards' then 'CEO'
    else 'None' end 
    as 'Boss Title'
    FROM maintable_L8MOQ where ReportsTo='Jenny Richards' or ReportsTo is null order by age;
```

Comment: please tag your sql engine.

Answer (score 6):

Use double quotes `"` around new column name. Here is the working [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wim8RtaKc5nc8FCHoKyAYu/0).

```
SELECT *,
    case when ReportsTo='Jenny Richards' then 'CEO'
    else 'None' end 
    as "Boss Title"
FROM maintable_L8MOQ 
where ReportsTo='Jenny Richards' or ReportsTo is null 
order by age;
```

Comment: i want to add the the new values as a column to my existing table not to my result

Comment: @anonymous_coder if possible create a new table and then run the following query using `insert` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can self-join the table or use a correlated subquery to bring the title of each employee's boss.

However, please note that your schema is not properly optimized for this. You should be referencing the `id` of the boss of each employee rather than its name: this would be more efficient (it avoids the need for string concatenation) and more accurate (there is no risk of homonyms).

For your current schema, that would be:

```
select l.*, coalesce(b.title, 'None') boss_title
from maintable_L8MOQ l
left join maintable_L8MOQ b 
    on concat(b.firstName, ' ', b.lastName) = l.reportsTo
order by l.age
```

Comment: here i want to check only if someone is reporting to jenny richards then i want to add the value as CEO to new column, if the reportsto value is null then i want the 'None' as value for my new column

Answer (score 0):

```
select FirstName,LastName,ReportsTO,Position,Age
      ,(case when ReportsTO='Jenny Richards' then 'CEO' 
             when ReportsTO is null then 'None' 
        else 'None' 
        end) as "Boss Title"
from maintable_H9LYD
where   ReportsTO = 'Jenny Richards' 
     or ReportsTO is null
order by age ASC
```

Comment: Always format the code (I did this time and you can approve) plus explain your code to make the OP aware how your code is different than others

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct answer

```
SELECT
  mt.ReportsTo, 
  COUNT(mt.ReportsTo) as Members, 
  ROUND(AVG(mt.AGe)) as Average_Age
FROM 
  maintable_7SKI5 mt
WHERE 
  ReportsTo is not null
GROUP BY 
  mt.ReportsTo
ORDER BY 
  mt.ReportsTo
```